# Using Google App Engine services outside of uploaded application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am looking to use Google Cloud Storage services outside of launching a google app engine application.  My application is designed for running on a hosted server of our own, and I would like to still use the cloud storage service.

I've written a dev app that did this, and ran it with dev_appserver.py in the python GAE framework.  It seems the dev_appserver.py is necessary as it fills in how to perform the RPC functions the cloud storage provides.

Is there a way to easily use google cloud storage service without the rest of it?

Comment: After doing some research outside of this, I ended up going with boto instead of using the google cloud storage services through the google app engine. boto supports google cloud storage, but more importantly, it was simpler, was easily adapted to use a different cloud storage system (s3, dreamobjects) and had straightforward tutorials to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There is gsutil command line tool:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

There is an xml/json restful service all at:
https://developers.google.com/storage/index

You'll need to enable the google cloud storage on the google console at:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and get the necessary api keys.

Comment: The APIs Console is going to be deprecated. The new version is Cloud Console: https://cloud.google.com/console

Comment: After doing some research outside of this, I ended up going with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) instead of using the google cloud storage services through the google app engine.

boto supports google cloud storage, but more importantly, it was simpler, was easily adapted to use a different cloud storage system (s3, dreamobjects) and had straightforward tutorials to do so.

Comment: We've been using boto for well over a year. Very, very solid library. Best part is not vendor specific.