# Google Storage Client Library from outside AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm curious, is there a way I could use the new Google Cloud Storage client library from outside AppEngine? If so, how would I go about setting the credentials/API key? I looked though the sparse documentation, to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338819/using-google-app-engine-services-outside-of-uploaded-application/18339204#18339204

Comment: The difference being that I'm asking about a very specific library whereas that other post asks the more general question.

Comment: ahh you're right I misunderstood, it looks like from source code its importing appengine only libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage and Google AppEngine are separate products that can be used seperately. AppEngine provides an AppEngine-specific client for Google Cloud Storage that provides several useful features for developing an AppEngine app that will use Google Cloud Storage, which I believe is the library you're referring to.

You can absolutely use Google Cloud Storage from outside AppEngine, but you cannot use AppEngine's GCS library to do so. Instead, you'll have to use one of GCS's APIs or client libraries. There are two main APIs (XML and JSON-based), and also client libraries for many major languages, including Python and Java.

For getting started, check out https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup

Comment: I was referring to the GCS client library specifically. Internally it leverages fetchurl which can be mocked, the crux of the issue is authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use gcs client from outside GAE, however you will still need to have the GAE SDK so the imports can work.

Take a look at the method [common.set_access_token](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/src/cloudstorage/common.py#60), you would need to refresh the token by yourself however.

If you are willing to dig further, you can take a look at the constructor of the [_RestApi](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/src/cloudstorage/rest_api.py#103) class which receives a token maker function.

This is an open source project and changes are welcomed.